# wxDialog inside wxWindows

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

when wx.Dialog is created it can take any position on the computer screen and take any dimension if style allows. I am trying to build dialogs and confine them within the application window.

I am not sure if my question is clear, I guess an online imagine would be a good example of what I need to do. 
in the current link, "spectra analysis" is an exact example of what I need.

http://cdn.altrn.tv/s/b80a7d76-3293-45f2-84dc-07ae136df1c6_1_full.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI in the image is using the Multiple Document Interface, and in wxPython on Windows you can get the same UI by using the `wx.MDIParentFrame` and `wx.MDIChildFrame`.  However be sure this is what you need because most users do not like MDI and even Microsoft abandonded it in their applications long ago.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want dialogs. You most likely want to look at the AUI widgets. There are the old wx.lib.aui widgets and the newer wx.lib.agw.aui widgets. I recommend the AGW version as it is written in pure Python and has had lots of enhancements done on it. I don't think the old wx.lib.aui widgets have had any attention in years.

See the wxPython demo for examples.